# Can I use almost and job together?

Tags: adverbs, adverbial-phrases, adverb-placement

My question, as I said in the title, is that can I use almost and job together? For example, is the sentence below correct (meaning and place of almost)?

> Unfortunately, there is almost no job related to my field.

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly use almost in this context. Note that job must be plural, as we only use singular for **one**. For zero/no/none, and for more than one, we use plural.

Comment: Thanks @JavaLatte for your comment. If jobs is correct, therefore I should use there are no jobs. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.